# How to bind Pin Location in MAUI

Tags: c#, maui

I need to fix a pin in a center of a screen and allow move on a map.

I added the map and pin:

```cs
map = new Map
{
    IsShowingUser = true,
    HeightRequest = deviceHeight,
    WidthRequest = deviceWidth,
};
map.PropertyChanged += OnMapPropertyChanged;
markerPin = new Pin
{

    Type = PinType.Place,
    Label = "Select Location",
    Location = MarkerLocation,

};
markerPin.SetBinding(Pin.LocationProperty, new Binding(nameof(MarkerLocation)));
map.Pins.Add(markerPin);
```

Added a property MarkerLocation

```cs
private Location markerLocation;

public Location MarkerLocation
{
    get
    {
        return markerLocation;
    }
    set
    {
        markerLocation = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("MarkerLocation");
    }
}
```

And if the map property has changed it update the MarkerLocation value:

```cs
private void OnMapPropertyChanged(object sender, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.PropertyName == "VisibleRegion" || e.PropertyName == "VisibleRegion.Center")
    {
        var center = map.VisibleRegion.Center;
        MarkerLocation = center;
    }
}
```

When I open the page I get the exception: "Java.Lang.IllegalArgumentException: 'latlng cannot be null - a position is required.'".
I tracked it down and found that after initialize the pin the SetBinding set "null" to pin location. If I write SetBinding before the initialization of pin I get a static pin that doesn't move even though the property MarkerLocation changes its value.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code and that you want to "fix a pin in a center of a screen and allow move on a map" this is a way to do that.

```cs
public class MapView : ContentPage
{
    private readonly Map map;
    private Location pos = new Location(59.3268215, 18.0717194);

    public MapCSharpView()
    {
        map = new Map(MapSpan.FromCenterAndRadius(pos, Distance.FromKilometers(0.5)))
        {
            IsShowingUser = true,
            Pins =
            {
                new Pin
                {
                    Type = PinType.Place,
                    Label = "Select Location",
                    Location = pos
                }
            }
        };
        map.PropertyChanged += OnMapPropertyChanged;
        Content = map;
    }

    private void OnMapPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.PropertyName == "VisibleRegion" || e.PropertyName == "VisibleRegion.Center")
        {
            var center = map.VisibleRegion.Center;
            if (Location.CalculateDistance(pos, center, DistanceUnits.Kilometers) > 0)
            {
                pos = center;
                map.Pins.Clear();
                map.Pins.Add(new Pin { Location = pos, Label = "Select Location", Type = PinType.Place });
                map.MoveToRegion(MapSpan.FromCenterAndRadius(pos, map.VisibleRegion.Radius));
            }
        }
    }
}
```